# how do I make the right references in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote this SQL script like this and I have no idea what's missing

```
create table Reggister(
stdNo CHAR(5),
courseID CHAR(8),
semesterID CHAR(5),
grade CHAR(2),
mark DECIMAL(4,2) check(BETWEEN 0.00 and 100.00),
foreign key (stdNo) references student(stdNo),
foreign key (courseID) references course(courseID),
foreign key (semesterID) references semester(semesterID),
primary key (stdNo, courseID, semesterID)
);
```

it'll give me something like
ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: At least `BETWEEN 0.00 and 100.00` should be `mark BETWEEN 0.00 and 100.00`.

Comment: thanks I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Holt's comment is the answer. The syntax for the `BETWEEN` operator is:

```
expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN low AND high
```

So you're just missing the expression to be tested in the range part of the check constraint. It should be:

```
check(mark BETWEEN 0.00 and 100.00)
```

The rest of your script works when the tables and columns in your foreign key declarations are present in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
create table Reggister(
stdNo CHAR(5),
courseID CHAR(8),
semesterID CHAR(5),
grade CHAR(2),
mark DECIMAL(4,2) check(mark BETWEEN 0.00 and 100.00),
foreign key (stdNo) references student(stdNo),
foreign key (courseID) references course(courseID),
foreign key (semesterID) references semester(semesterID)
);
```